# How to apply css styles in embed widget

Tags: css, widget, sass, less, stylus

I create widgets for sites which I don't own.

After injecting html, I do the following to style the widget:

```
var style = document.createElement('style'),
    stylesString = 'minified css with a prefix for each selector eg. .my-prefix p {... }',
    rules = document.createTextNode(stylesString);

style.type = 'text/css';
if(style.styleSheet) {
    style.styleSheet.cssText = rules.nodeValue;
} else {
    style.appendChild(rules);
}
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
```

But on some sites my styles are overridden.

Is there a way to apply the styles more precisely?

I don't want (can't) to use:

- iFrame
- !important on every property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely caused by the elements in question either having inline styles on them (for which you will have to use `!important` to override, if you want to use your current method of adding styles), or having styles with a higher [selector precedence](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/).

My suggestion would be to make your selectors more specific by adding at least an `id` to them - although this is still no guarantee your selectors will still be the most specific. It is entirely down to the quality of the stylesheet on the original site.

Comment: I would like to omit the use of ids because the widget is placed on external sites. I was thinking more in a direction to parse the css and apply the styles via javascript to specific elements...